# Is it possible to run Mongo client shell query/commands from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Could I use the Mongo client shell queries/commands from inside Ruby?

I know there is the Ruby driver DSL, but I was thinking about something similar to running a SQL query from within PHP.

Just for the sake of knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always work directly with the MongoDB Ruby driver. Read [this tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Tutorial) for more information.